# struct segmentation fault gcc on raspberry pi

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, struct, malloc

I'm struggling with a small amount of C code trying to get to run on a RPI2b.

The code is about creating a struct including a integer array with a dynamic size.

The struct file has to be declared as a pointer in my main function.

This is because: The bigger purpose of my program will be executing three Array iterations in parallel by the use of pthread.

As  far as I know pthread needs a pointer in function call.
I don't want to change anything by using pthread (never change a winning team).

This is what my code snipping should do:

- define a STEP number
- declare a static int array with defined amount of STEP
- declare a struct including a dynamic array
- fill up the static int array
- allocate memory for dynamic array
- fill up dynamic array with values of static int array
- print both on console

No errors while compiling with gcc!

The Problem is that when it Comes to allocate memory for the dynamic array program simply pints a "Segmentation fault" on the console.

The fun fact is: I've copied paste the whole code to Visual Studio 2017 and it works perfectly fine!

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define STEPS 50 //defined steps

typedef struct file File;

struct file {
    int type;
    int* array; //dynamic array
};

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    int mainarray[STEPS] = { 0 };
    struct file *f = (File*)malloc(sizeof(File)); //allocate memory for struct

    printf("Fill up static array\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= STEPS; i++) {
        mainarray[i] = i;
    }
    printf("static array values:\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= STEPS; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", mainarray[i]);
    }
    printf("allocate memory for dynamic array\n");
    f->array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * STEPS); //Here I receive my segmentation fault
    if (f->array == NULL) {
        printf("allocating error\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= STEPS; i++) {
        f->array[i] = 20000 * mainarray[i];
    }

    printf("compare of arrays\n");

    for (i = 0; i <= STEPS; i++) {
        printf("i:=\t%d\tMainarray:\t%d\tStructarray:\t%d\t\n", i, mainarray[i], f->array[i]);
    }
    free(f->array);
    free(f);
}
```

Comment: You clearly seem to know that array indexes in C are zero-based (i.e. start at zero). But because of that, for an array of e.g. `STEPS` elements, what is the *max* index possible?

Comment: On another note, why do you allocate memory for the structure dynamically?

Comment: Dynamic allocation: Thanks for replying! Another Point of my purpose is that in the final version the number of steps will be dependet on a external file loaded into the code. Therefore the number of STEPS will be different (shouldnt be stet as a #define I see right now. Sorry for that!)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is (see comment from Some Programmer Dude) that you go out of bounds of your array. That causes undefined behavior, in your case resulting in a seg fault.

```
for (i = 0; i <= STEPS; i++)
```

should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < STEPS; i++)
```

because `STEPS-1` is the *last* valid array element.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect now! just replaced STEPS with STEPS-1 (even in allocation).

Comment: One more question left: Why doesnt it work vice versa? When I try to run the for Loop up to STEPS and allocate (STEPS+1) I will Keep receving a Segmentation error...

Comment: You don't want to go to `STEPS-1` You want your condition to be `i < STEPS`. That's how we normally do it in C. As to your question: everything then needs to be size `STEPS+1`, starting with `mainarray[STEPS+1]`.